# Edit opacity of Plot3D after creation

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have just created a 3D surface plot with the function `Plot3D`.
Now, I want to change the opacity of the graph, after I have created it, without having to redraw the graph.

I am able to change things like axislabels etc., but I cannot find how I can change the opacity after creation.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does `Show[plot, BaseStyle -> Opacity[.5]]` work for you?

Comment: That works great! What if I use the function `Show[plot1,plot2]` and I only want to change the opacity of plot1? If I use `Show[plot1, plot1, BaseStyle -> Opacity[.5]]`, both plots get Opacity 0.5.

Comment: Peter, `BaseStyle` affects everything that is not explicitly styled, so by nature it will affect both plots; there can be only one `BaseStyle` for the combined `Graphics3D` expression.  Working with the primitives is more flexible.

Comment: Or, you could probably nest `Show` commands (e.g. `Show[Show[plot1,BaseStyle -> Opacity[.5]], plot2]`. I have not tried. Anyway Mr.Wizard's suggestion is probably better :)

Comment: Mr. Wizard's answer is indeed the way to go! Thanks:)

Comment: @anderstood No, that actually doesn't work because only one `BaseStyle` directive is retained.

Comment: Final question: what if I do want to change the color of plot, without changing it using `Show`?

Comment: Changing a color is harder as you have to replace a directive that already exists in the plot. The method used may need to change depending on the source of the plot.  For the example I chose we can use something as simple as `plot /. _Directive :> Opacity[.5, Red]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To affect the primitives only and not the frame, labels, etc.:

```
plot = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]

plot // MapAt[{Opacity[0.5], #} &, 1]
```

[image]